# Recursive form input addition in Meteor

Tags: javascript, forms, recursion, meteor

I have an app that you can create invoices with. I want to be able to have multiple job fields, that users can add.

```
<div class="row desc">
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <h5 class="dmno-txt invoice-field border line-num" id="item-0-num">1</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
    <div class="form-control-wrapper">
      <input class="dmno-green form-control empty" type="text" placeholder="What was this job" id="item-0-desc" value={{lineItem0}} step="any">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="form-control-wrapper">
      <input class="form-control empty" type="number" placeholder="How much?" step="any" id="total-0" value={{total0}}>
      <span class="material-input"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="togglebutton">
      <label class="tax-toggle-label">
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggleTax-0"><span class="toggle"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That is what a single one looks like, I wonder how I can create a button with a Meteor event to add a `row` like that recursively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this.

```
Template.example.events(){
  'click #buttonExample':function(){
     var exampleStack = $(".row");
     $("body").append(d[0].cloneNode(true)); 
  }
}
```

this [jsFildde](https://jsfiddle.net/wvgrkton/) its just to have an idea of what this code does.

Comment: thanks @Ethaan , however, I need all the id's and numbers to dynamically change from 1 to 2, 3, etc.